# Optimizing the design of a backend search engine

Tags: mongodb, optimization, elasticsearch, redis

> **TL;DR**: this question is about `optimizing the design of a backend search engine`: the idea is to return a fully-formed html page that displays search results as quickly as possible.

I figured [elasticsearch](http://www.elasticsearch.org/) and [redis](http://redis.io/) would be suitable candidates for the job, though I have not decided yet.
The server will be [node.js](http://nodejs.org/), the database [mongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/).

> No frontend framework will be used, plain html will be returned by the server.

---

### I came up with the following server-side design*:

(*) *NOTE: I have little experience in server-side designing, so my approach is probably naive*

A *first search* would:

```
- run a server function that makes an elasticSearch query and returns some json;

- create scraps of HTML from the returned json and store them in Redis
  (for caching purposes);

- store the search keywords and the keys of the html scraps in Redis.
```

Whereas *subsequent searches* would just:

```
- recognize the search keywords, and get the html scraps keys from Redis;

- get the html scraps values;
```

The server would then:

```
- build the html page from the scraps; 

- Return the html page.
```

---

### Let's elaborate further with an example:

Imagine you have a rather large collection of articles, say 100,000, which you intend to sell on your website.

`All articles are stacked in a MongoDb database` and have multiple keys (title, categories, reviews, pictures, etc...)

To implement search, the article collection has been `indexed in elasticSearch`.

A first elasticSearch query would return a `json containing a list of articles`.

Subsequent queries to elasticSearch, with the same search terms, would return the same json, but would now `extract it from the elasticSearch cache`.

But if you're NOT using frontend technology and want `plain html` returned from the server, you would still need to `insert that json into a templator, create an html page, then return to the end user`.

- If you cached the `whole html page into a superfast key/value database like Redis`, neither the templator nor elasticSearch would be used on subsequent searches: Redis would recognise the search terms, and return the html straight away.
- Or if, as suggested in the comments/answers, Redis was skipped, the `html could be stored into a cdn` after it has been computed by the templator.

---

### The question:

> Please specify which steps of suggested design are unnecessary/missing, and why.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: You don't need Redis for the caching as EL takes care of all those and it's scalable the same way. http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/filter-caching.html

Comment: Ok. But wouldn't it be slower, as ElasticSearch stores json only? Wouldn't the templator have more work to do if it didn't fetch scraps of html?

Comment: You should not store the entire HTML, you don't need that phase, as EL responds in under 50ms with your results.

Comment: Do you know how many request/sec will you have guaranteed? (not estimate as that is volatile). What's your expected response time, I need to ask this because I think you put in the same bucket time of templating and time of accessing from storage. While the first one I think will be under 1ms, the later on a good cluster could be 50ms. Maybe you will have another 50ms from all the other routes (DNS, load-balancer, logging), so I think that this way you can serve under 110ms the whole static thing

Comment: For hot/trending static pages, you could have easily a Varnish before your chosen web server, and that could carry 10k ops/sec for.

Comment: @Pentium10: Thanks for your comment. Serving under 110ms would be perfect! I had no idea templating was so fast; in fact, I thought it would be the slowing factor! As of yet, I have no idea how many requests/sec the website will get, it is still early development

Comment: Please be aware scripting is very fast, you can have 4billions of operation under a second. Anything that's outside of the code has a general latency and it's a bit slower.

Comment: @Pentium10 Would storing scraps of  html into a cdn make sense at all?

Comment: Only if CDN costs are less then paying for a instance which can generate it on the fly. I think that you are going too much ahead, and you will have a lot of other problems and not these.

Comment: @Pentium10 you are probably right! One last question: why don't you post an answer? :)

Comment: I will summarize these into an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Summary from comments:

1. You don't need Redis for the caching as EL takes care of all those and it's scalable the same way. http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/filter-caching.html
2. You should not store the entire HTML, you don't need that phase, as EL responds in under 50ms with your results.
3. For hot/trending static pages, you could have easily a Varnish before your chosen web server, and that could carry 10k ops/sec
4. Use CDN, Only if CDN costs are less than paying for a instance which can generate it on the fly.
5. Don't put in the same bucket time of templating and time of accessing from storage. While the first one I think will be under 1ms, the later - on a good cluster could be 50ms. Maybe you will have another 50ms from all the other routes (DNS, load-balancer, logging), so I think that this way you can serve under 110ms the whole static thing.

   - if you will go with Elasticsearch, you don't need MongoDB at all, as EL is also a document storage.

Comment: it seems CDN costs can indeed be prohibitive for huge websites like SO: "A CDN is not used because even “cheap” CDNs like Amazon one are very expensive relative to the bandwidth they get bundled into their existing host’s plan. The least they could pay is $1k/month based on Amazon’s CDN rates and their bandwidth usage. ". See: http://highscalability.com/blog/2011/3/3/stack-overflow-architecture-update-now-at-95-million-page-vi.html

Answer (score 2):

IMHO you don't want to use REDIS but just query elasticsearch for this.
ES is a pretty sophisticated search engine that should get you quite far out of the box.
If you use REDIS for caching you are going to query redis first and in case you got a CACHE_MISS you query elasticsearch. 
I recommend this youtube video to get a first impression what magic elasticsearch is handing you over: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=52G5ZzE0XpY

BTW: elasticsearch does not store 'only json', if stores key/values but the values are stored as efficient as possible. If it's an int it is stored as an interger...

EDIT: And I would suggest using kibana, at least during the development phase. If you are pleased with what you query through kibana, you might create your plain html website. 
Furthermore you might want to have a look at elasticsearch-kopf to get insights into ES.

Comment: thanks, watched the video, and yes, elasticSearch is a great tool. I understand the search engine could work with or without Redis. However, what I am trying to figure out is the best compromise between simplicity (no Redis=one less technology to implement) and maximum efficiency (no unnecessary elasticSearch queries, no unnecessary templating): see edited question, where I added an example section, to try and detail my train of thought a little more...